# Generate hair by using vertex groups as a guide

Tags: geometry-nodes, weight-painting, hair, vertex-groups

I have tried to guide the hair using vertex groups, even using weight paint, but it does not help.

I use the new hair system in Blender 4.0 on Windows 11.
[image: weight pa]

Is it possible to use vertex groups to place hair curves at the desired location, as in the image?

Here is my file

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add hair to a painted area, use the "Generate Hair Curves" node.

Edit the node: Add a vertex group attribute and use a Boolean math node with the Not operation attached to the Delete Geometry node.

[image: Generate hair curves node tree]

[image: Result]

[image]

Comment: I already do as you asked but I get this result instead  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YXj3bfbbBLVRERnZvDasIfjumW5p1SVS/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: @erasvinzz
Do you use empty hair for the modifiers?
I attached a file with my answer, you can copy the hair system from there.

Comment: no I didn't I just use modifier generate hair curve...  Should I use empty hair for this to work?

Comment: It appears that you have applied a modifier to an object (suzanne), so it will delete geometry that is not related to the curves.

Comment: Yes, I use hair system modifier"Generate Hair Curve"

Comment: Are you applying this modifier to another object?
If not, you should apply it to "Empty Hair" or simply copy my file.

Comment: I see your file and I found the problem. Turn out I didn't copy named attributes node for generate hair curve node socket for surface uv map and I also didnt use fur hair